# recursion is not ending with the return statement in js

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

Here is a simple program to check if num is a power of 2 or not, for that I used recursion. somehow it is not working. I added a breakpoint and found that the program is running and it is going into return true and return false but even after that it is returning undefined.

```
function check2Pow(num)
{

    function check(i)
    {
        let pow=Math.pow(2,i);
        if(pow === num)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(pow > num)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            check(i+1);
        }

    }


    return check(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write `return` before `check(i+1)`. If you omit `return`, the result of any recursion is ignored and never passed back to the original caller.

You can also use this one-liner to know if you have a power of 2:

```js
Math.log(num)/Math.log(2) % 1 === 0
```

Comment: there's also `!+num.toString(2).substring(1)` - which works for `BigInt` values as a bonus